What to do about this light fixture mounting?
This is a wall sconce.  I discovered that it is simply hanging on a bent nail.  Behind it (it simply lifts off the nail) there is what appears to be a standard lamp cord.  This is wire-nutted to the supply wires in a box with no cover.
Please tell me this was not the OEM installation method!  Is there a safe way to remedy this without replacing the actual fixture?



Ground wire is missing.  Is this an ungrounded electrical system?

Quite a lot of the house has bo ground.  We've been slowly updating.

The main concern right now would those threads showing, unless locked tight.

Threads?  Do explain

Give us a shot of the back of the sconce.

At the top of the light where the chain attaches.  Unknown if that is as close as the two pieces get(tight) or just hanging on by one or two threads.

The fact that we see gold lamp cord behind the lamp housing suggests that this was not intended for permanent installation to a box. I think I see a notch at the bottom where the cord would've protruded, and it probably had a wall plug on it. Someone retrofitted it for this use case.
One possible approach would be to install a standard outlet and cover plate, and install a low-profile plug on the lamp cord, leaving it mounted as it is. This effectively reverts it to its intended usage.
Or, depending on what's inside the lamp housing, mount the kind of bar that ships with modern lamps and use that to mount to the box. Without a view inside that's about as specific as I can be.
In any case, extend the box so it's legal. You should find parts at your electrical supplier that simply mate to the existing box, which looks fairly standard.
